# Executing a program based on a new environment variable

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

I'm installing nodeJS through powershell and afterwards I need to run some `npm` commands in a powershell window.

The powershell process only has access to the environment variables that were available when the process was started, not the newly created `npm` environment variable added during installation.

I thought I could get around this by launching a new powershell process from my first powershell script to execute the next part of the installation but this also fails with the message

> the term 'npm' is not recognised

Here's the line I use to launch the new powershell process:

`Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit", "-Command $PSScriptRoot/Part2.ps1",  -UseNewEnvironment, -LoadUserProfile`

(This is in Part1.ps1)

How do I get a powershell process to run that can see the `npm` environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by obtaining the current Path environment variable from the registry and overwriting the current process' Path variable.

```
$regKey = "HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"

$regItem = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -Name Path 

$env:Path = $regItem.Path
```

Now when I call `npm`, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue with the PSCX installer.  It modifies an environment variable but PowerShell processes don't pick up the change until the user logs out and back in again.  Another approach is to read the machine wide environment variable value from the registry.

```
$path = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' Path).Path
```

Comment: I don't want to inherit the parent process' environment block. The new enviro var isn't scoped to the parent because it's created after the process has started.

Comment: Ah, the installation process is modifying the machine environment variables and the PowerShell process isn't picking that up?  I've encountered this with the PSCX installation. Bothersome.  You'd probably have better luck querying the registry for the npm variable under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

Comment: Keith, your last comment was really helpful. I reset the enviro path property based on the path reg key. I'll add what I did as an answer buy feel free to add also and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter of `Start-Process` to point it to the location where `npm` is. Or, you can resolve the path to `npm` inside of the `part1.ps1` script. If the `part1.ps1` script sits side-by-side with the `npm` command, you can point to `npm` as follows:

```
$npm = "$PSScriptRoot\npm.exe";
. $npm -Arg1 -Arg2;
```

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I'd have to query to registry to determine where the user had installed nodeJS (it installs with the msi) which is a bit messier than querying the registry for the Path enviro var. Between the two answers here I got to the solution so thanks again.